# Will github push all files to master after merging from master or just the single file from the conflict solved

Tags: git, github

I am facing the following scenario. I have merge conflict after pushing my `local branch` to `master`.

my local branch name `some_branch`.

- now I went to master, typed: `git pull`
- I returned to my local branch: `git checkout some_branch`
- at this point my local branch has no changes, then i typed: `merge master`
- Github told me to resolve the conflict on `visual studio` and I did.
- Now here is my situation:

When I look at `git status` I **HAVE ALL THE CHANGES** from `master` to my branch and below the untracked files of the conflict i just resolved.

Now my question:
- if i do `git add -A`
- `git commit -m "solved merge conflict"`
- `git push origin master`

After pushing to `master`, is `github` also going to include all the files received from `master` above after I merged? (because I can see them when i do `git status`) or just the file from the conflict that I solved?

Comment: This is strictly a `git` question, you should probably remove the `javascript`, `java`, and `python` tags as they are not relevant to your question.

Comment: @pciunkiewicz done. any thoughts on the question?

Comment: I would recommend tackling it using a GUI such as SourceTree, GitKraken, or the GitLens extension in VSCode. That approach (in my opinion) makes both the order and result of the git operations more clear and might allow you to make sense of what the best step is (appologies for a lack of concrete answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A commit is a snapshot of your *entire* workspace — except for those files that you have never told git about by saying `add`, or that you have deliberately told git to ignore using a *.gitignore* file. In short: ***Every* commit contains *all* the files.** Not just the ones you changed. All of them.

A merge commit is no exception to that rule.

A merge commit made after resolving a conflict is no exception to that rule either.

That's because there are *no* exceptions to that rule.

Now, what's a push? It copies commits. Therefore the remote (github), too, will have *all* the files after push.

---

<sub>It's interesting that you mention `git status` in this regard, because it can be misleading. It doesn't list all the files. It lists only the files "of interest." But nevertheless, each actual commit contains *all* the files. If you actually want to know what *all* the files are, use `ls-files` or `ls-tree`. In particular `ls-tree` will answer your question by telling you all the files in the commit you are about to push to github. Try something like `git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD`.</sub>